# Modeling "Likes" in rails HABTM vs HM/BT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, social-networking

What would be the best method to model "likes" in rails for my app. I could either to the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things

  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_things, through: :likes, source: :thing
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thing
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

Or

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things

  has_and_belongs_to_many :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

What approach would be best and why? I plan to have an activity feed in my app as well, if that helps determine the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on whether or not `Like` will ever have any attributes or methods.

If its *only* purpose of existence is to be the HABTM relationship between `User`s and `Thing`s, then using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship would suffice. In your example, having `has_many` and `belongs_to` is redundant. All you would need in this case is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

On the other hand, if you anticipate that a `Like` will have an attribute (e.g. maybe someone will *really* like something, or love it, etc.) then you can do

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_things, through: :likes, source: :thing
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thing
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

Note that I removed `has_many :things` and `belongs_to :user` as they are redundant.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It actually wasn't redundant, it's just another association, as in the user owns things or can create things that belong to him.

Comment: Like could be useful for other reasons, e.g. tracking the date one liked a thing, or simply for querying purposes (show last 10 likes of a thing by all users, etc).  And though it may not be pertinent here, you may not use HABTM if the `Thing` will be polymorphic.

Comment: Yeah, seems the join model is what I'm gonna be going for, just to keep my options open.

Comment: Plus HABTM is just gross.

Comment: @8vius Ok, those are certainly valid associations. Consider them removed then for purposes of isolating the question at hand :)